# jquery .when() fires done callback whereas deferred object is pending

Tags: jquery

I am running this code on a DESKTOP browser (Chrome for Linux) :

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
        deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}
$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
        console.log('JQM is ready');
        jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});
$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then( doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded(), failure() );
function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
            alert('success :deviceReadyDeferred is '+deviceReadyDeferred.state());
            console.log('Phonegap and JQM are loaded');
            EVERYTHING();
}
```

and the `alert` gives : `success :deviceReadyDeferred is pending`...whereas it shouldn't even fire, should it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When in doubt about promises, mock up a simple JSFiddle to test the theory: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/68X6j/1/ As Arun P Johny points out you are calling the function instead of passing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass function references to the `then()` method as arguments, do not invoke the callback methods while calling `then()`(by adding `()` at the end of function name)

```
$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded, failure);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sP4aX/)

Comment: well actually, it seems it doesn't work that well....in my function called EVERYTHING() I put all the jquery mobile events....and the app is stuck on the first (splash) page.

Comment: adding the parenteses, generates another problem, all the jquery mobile bindings made in EVERYTHING() are not accounted for, posted a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827726/deferred-jquery-mobile-statements-into-when-callback